# jade.tmbundle not working with textmate

Tags: bundle, pug, textmate

I installed [Jade.TmBundle](https://github.com/miksago/jade-tmbundle) for Textmate 2.0-alpha.9547 (according to instructions) but does not work.

There is no syntax highlighting for .jade files.

When I open bundles (form Preferences) it shows bundle selected, but when I try to unselect and select again in simple, doesn't select.

Can anyone help?

**Updated**:

Found a new bundle that works like a charm: https://github.com/davidrios/jade-tmbundle

Comment: Your answer worked for me. SublimeText and TM Bundles are generally interchangeable, it seems.